# how to use http2 in loopback 4 application?

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

We are planning to implement http2 in a loopback 4 application. We had used http, socket servers but never http2.

What is the procedure to use http2 in my application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/69868/miroslav-bajto%c5%a1 https://stackoverflow.com/users/5019371/rifa-achrinza is this even possible to do so??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you have to do in your existing app:

#### Step 1: Install [spdy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spdy)

```bash
npm i spdy
```

#### Step 2: Configure `index.ts`

Change your main function in `src/index.ts` with this:

```
import spdy from "spdy";

export async function main(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
  
  // specify cert and key file paths for SSL
  const serverOptions: spdy.ServerOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(
      path.join(__dirname, '..', 'keys', 'localhost-privkey.pem'),
    ),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(
      path.join(__dirname, '..', 'keys', 'localhost-cert.pem'),
    ),
  };

  // setting listenOnStart to false will not start the default httpServer
  options.rest.listenOnStart = false;

  // Replace YourApplication with your class
  const app = new YourApplication(options);
  await app.boot();
  await app.start();

  // create server
  const server = spdy.createServer(serverOptions, app.requestHandler);

  // to avoid process exit on warnings
  server.on('warning', console.warn);

  server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on https://localhost:3000/');
  });

  return app;
}
```

All we're doing in the above code is, preventing the default http server from being started and starting the server using spdy with loopback's request handler `app.requestHandler` that will be used for all incoming request.

> Check out this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/F5gD1aF2) containing entire `index.ts` file content after the changes.

To generate certificate and keys for localhost use:

```bash
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -subj '/CN=localhost' \
  -keyout localhost-privkey.pem -out localhost-cert.pem
```

You may need to allow self-signed certificates in Chrome as well for `/explorer` to work as expected.

And that's it, you can now run your app, and enjoy the power of http2 :)

Blog Post: https://shubham-web.medium.com/how-to-use-http2-in-loopback-4-applications-5e83881c7b38